# Minecraft server spawn command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

What command do I use to spawn to a different area in my Minecraft server?

I spawned on a island and there is no land near?

I really need help and my friends want to join and they are getting tried of waiting.

Comment: as I understand it your asking for the command to move the server's spawnpoint?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming I understand your question correctly, you want to change your worlds spawnpoint. Doing this is easy, what you need to do is go to where you want your spawnpoint to be and while standing at the designated place you've decided on, type;

> /setworldspawn

It may be helpfull to first convert your world to creative mode so you can fly around and find a suitable location easier, then, before you invite your friends change your world back to survival mode.

> /gamemode survival
>   /gamemode creative

Answer (score 1):

If you are using vanilla Minecraft server, /setworldspawn will do the job perfectly. If you are on a CraftBukkit server, try /setspawn or /gm 0 for survival and /gm 1 for creative.